# Google App Engine - Add & Reflect pattern, working around eventual consistency

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm building a web application on app engine.
In my case, that's built on django-nonrel, but the key point is that it's using Google's datastore.

I love the fact that I don't need to deal with replication, sharding, backups and such, but one thing that is always getting in my way is the eventual consistency, which seems to get in the way of implementing a common web app pattern which I'm calling "Add & Reflect".

Let's say I have a project management app. The Project is its central model.
Now there's a web page page where I see a list of all projects, can add a project, and then I'll reflect back the list of all projects, which should include the project I just added (assuming no errors).

So the pattern goes like this:

1. Get and display list of existing projects
2. User adds new project (using a form on that page)
3. New project is created
4. As a response, get and display list of existing projects (now includes the new project)

Now the thing is, that due to eventual consistency, there is no guarantee whatsoever that I will get that new project when I get a list of all projects right after adding a new project.
Now that would be fine if this momentary inconsistency happened when another request (e.g. another user: user B) requested the list of projects one second after the project was added by the first user (user A), but it's really a problem when user A performs an operation, and does not see the results of his action, therefore does not get feedback.

I have gotten used to doing something like this to work around this problem:

```
def create_project(request):
    response_context = {}
    new_project = Project(name=request.POST['name'])
    project.save()
    response_context['projects'] = Project.get_serialized_projects()
    # on GAE, eventual consistency means we are not guaranteed to see the
    # new projects while querying for all projects, therefore we might need 
    # to add it manually...
    if project.serialize() not in response_context['projects']:
        response_context['projects'].append(project.serialize())
    return render('projects.html', response_context)
```

The problem is that this happens in many places in my code, so I'm thinking maybe I'm missing something there, since this pattern is such a basic web app pattern.

Any suggestions for other ways to handle this?

Comment: store the generated key from saving the model, then use it to pull the model? so key = project.save(), then use key to pull the model for use?

Comment: `object.save()` does not return a key in django-nonrel, but you can indeed fetch the key from `object.id` after you `save()`, and do a `get(id=id)`, but this is essentially the same as I'm suggesting, doing an extra fetch to get the object which might me missing from the query due to the eventual consistency. The disadvantage of this solution is that it entails another datastore hit (speed, cost).

Comment: ah, yes, I suppose I would have been better to say the get by key will always work, so pass that around if available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its a common issue. No theres no magic fix.
From client-side once you know the commit succeeded you can save the item locally (globals or storage) and then when querying from datastore merge your saved data. Put an expiration on it so its temporary. Its not trivial to make it work in all cases (say added an item then removed/renamed it so also update cache etc).
From server-side its common to cache recent saves in memcache and also merge with your queries.